# How to center all img in css with flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, flexbox, center

i have a very noob question now, but I dont get it, how i can get center an item from a flexbox like this

[image: doubt]
[image: how it really looks]
[image: description]

```css
.productos_Imagenes{
    width: 150px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
.contenedor_Linea_1{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.linea_1_Tipos{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor_Linea_ 1">
    <div>Linea de Productos 1</div>
    <div>Sabores</div>
    <div class="linea_1_Tipos">Frutales</div>
    <div class="contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores">
        <div class="contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\frutillas.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\mango.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\melon.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\sandia.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\naranja.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\uva.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\frambuesa.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\frutos del bosque.png">
        </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="linea_1_Tipos"> No Frutales</div>
    <div class="contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores">
        <div class="contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\cafe.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\vainilla.png">
             <img class="productos_Imagenes" src="C:\Users\Rodrigo\Desktop\Proyecto Sitio\Data Productos 1\whisky.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your css add `.contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor { text-align: center; }`

Comment: thx it works, I'm surprised it's so simple

Comment: also the parent box of the images isn't set to display flex-box

Comment: This has nothing to do with flexbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flexbox, you could do something like https://jsfiddle.net/k3bnsv24/18/.

I tried to recreate your case. For you, it would mean that ".contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor" should be the equivalent of ".container"

```
    .contenedor_Linea_1_Sabores_Contenedor {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these:-

1. Using margin:
    `img { margin: auto; }`
2. Cover you image: `img { width: 100%; object-fit: cover;}`